# What Changes has Patch 4.20 Made To ARAM?

Tags: league-of-legends

I played some ARAMs last night after the new patch and aside from the changes to items/champions I can't notice a different in ARAM. I assume new health regen statistics will affect the global health regen buf. But is that it, have we been forgotten about again? We didn't even get the new towers!

Comment: And why couldn't you take some time to read the patch notes since the version you want to know what changed to the latest one? Or are you planning to do it and answer your question? And that downvote wasn't from me.

Comment: There're no changes listed for ARAM in patch 4.20 http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-420-notes

Comment: I read all the patch notes. But I was expecting to see the tower changes.

Comment: If it's not in the patchnotes nothing has changed:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Only the Champion- and item-changes affect ARAM

Aside from that, **no changes to the map** where made.

Comment: Unfortunately this is the answer.